# Can AutoCAD connect to PostGIS (specifically for Ordnance Survey Mastermap)?

Tags: postgis, autocad, os-mastermap

As per title.

Can up to date (2019) AutoCAD versions be practically/safely connected to a PostGIS database.

And more specifically does this work well/practically/safely for accessing Ordnance Survey Mastermap data? What are the limitiations?

Comment: Yes (AutoCAD Map 3D) but you need the right drivers https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Connection-to-PostGreSql-Postgis.html what version of PostGIS are you running?

Comment: Thanks (we should turn your comment into an answer). I'm not the admin for the PostGIS database - standard coorporate structure (GIS staff != IT staff). Does it make a difference? Can I check this using pgAdmin? Database was installed probably around 2 years ago. - At the moment I don't have to do this, but I'm increasingly becoming the 'please export us mapping for AutoCAD' officer, and I'm wondering if I need to tell my AutoCAD using colleagues about how they should be using their software more efficiently.

Comment: Without seeing your setup you will have try, if you get an issue report/new question. Try not to get to off-topic ( https://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be a better source of answers)

Comment: That's OK - I only needed the theoretical yes/no to begin with. Happy to chase up my individual circumstances alone. I could still do with a theoretical yes/no on the Mastermap question (will be a pretty standard usage in the UK so seems fair to ask this here).

Comment: fyi MasterMap is GB only.. (Not Northern Ireland)

Comment: Oops - yes, fair point. Habit arising from tweeting using 'UK' for shorter tweets rather than something more specific (GB less well understood internationally I think). I've made that mistake before.